# Display row and column number based on active cell in specific range

Tags: excel, vba

I have some VBA code that displays the row and column number of the active cell in the respective named ranges: **State_Row** and **State_Column**.

```vb
Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Sheet1.Range("State_Row").Value = ActiveCell.Row

Sheet1.Range("State_Column").Value = ActiveCell.Column

End Sub
```

This works fine, however, I want it to only apply to the range D10:E65, so if the user clicks outside this range, the row and column numbers do not update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect) method:

```
Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

if intersect(target,range("D10:E65")) is nothing then exit sub

Sheet1.Range("State_Row").Value = target.Row 'use target

Sheet1.Range("State_Column").Value = target.Column

End Sub
```